# Rellenar valores nulls con el último valor no null en una misma columna

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de rellenar registros de una columna donde tengo valores nulls de forma entrecortada con el último valor no null de la misma columna. Les muestro una imagen de lo que quiero . Estoy tratando de evitar usar Procedural Language .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sergio, bienvenido a SOes. Como comentario general, considera hacer el [tour]. Que has intentando hasta ahorita? Puedes mostrarnos?

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que los datos están ordenados por `id1`, dado un registro cualquiera que tenga `NULL`, puedes obtener el valor "anterior" con:

```
select top 1 angulo
from tabla 
where id1 < @id and not angulo is null
order by id1 desc
```

**Nota**: estoy usando T-SQL ya que no especificaste con qué DBMS estás...

Ahora bien, si esto lo quieres para todas las columnas que tienen `NULL`, podrías usar la consulta anterior como subconsulta:

```
select *, (
    select top 1 angulo
    from tabla as B
    where B.id1 < A.id1 and not angulo is null
    order by id1 desc) as angulo_calculado
from tabla as A
where angulo is NULL
```

Luego que verifiques que esos son los datos que quieres, hacer el *update* debería ser bastante directo.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta! No especifiqué perdón , trabajo con pgadmin - postgres. Cambié el top 1 por un limit 1 al final para emular el comando , ya que no tiene Top pgadmin , pero el tiempo de la query es lento  con 7 millones de registros.